# Can I connect to a SQL Server that is external to my network?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, networking

I'm not sure if this is possible.

My office Pc sits on the corporate network and to access anything outside this network I have to provide my username and password to get though the proxy.

We have recently purchased a hosted server external to this network so that we can host demo applications that can be access from anywhere. However when we need to connect to the server to update or work on the database we need to use a PC that is not on our network as there is no way to provide my username and password as either part of a connection string or in the management console.

The external server is running SQL Server 2008.

Any advise would be much appreciated as I'm not sure if this is even possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an http tunnel between the server and the computer from which you want to access the SQL server.
Use HTTPtunnel GNU package for the organization HTTP tunnel.
[Here an example of a HTTP tunnel to connect to the MySQL server.](http://www.mysql-tools.com/articles/http-tunnel/73-heidisql-a-http-tunnel.html)
To connect to SQL server you must specify the appropriate port.

Comment: Thanks Devid - this seems like the answer, buy my network guy just told me that Proxies and Anonymizers will be knocked back by the corporate network adn the HTTP tunnel will fall into that category - this is outside of my understanding so apologies if this hasn't worded properly!

Comment: timately in my situation this is not possible, althout Devid G's asnwer would work in certian cases and I've accepted it because of this - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try to use [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com).
1. Installed on the server TeamViewer ... during the installation process specify a fixed password for remote access. remember or write ID (9 digits)
2. on your work computer install teamviewer.
connect to remote server ID and password.